# The best way to read a lot of messages from RabbitMQ queue?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I'm writing Python script cron-job, which is periodically get updates from RabbitMQ and process them. Every time I process them I need only to get current snapshot of RMQ queue. I use queue_declare to get number of messages in it.
I know how to get messages one by one with basic_get. Also, I can use basic_consume/start_consuming and get messages in background, store them in some list and periodically get from that list, but what if script will fail with some error? I will lost all read messages in list. Also, I can use few consumers (pool of connections to RMQ) and get messages one by one. Maybe there is some other approach to do it?

So, my question is - what is the best (i.e. secure and fast) way to get current messages from RabbiMQ queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to consume the messages is using `basic_consume`.
`basic_get` is slow

Comment: Sounds like true, but what if I stop script (or some error occurs) while consuming? Is there any specific issue?

Comment: You need to learn how RabbitMQ works, specifically the process of acknowledging messages and what happens when they aren't acknowledged - https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html